# Create url link within free text

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linkify PHP text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250216/linkify-php-text)

Hi I have a field from a database that contains http links as well as normal text.

I need to find out a way to display this information using PHP to show Text and a  link when applicable.

the following is my sql query:

```
  $sql =
   "select bw_supporting_doc
    from cm3rm2 with(nolock)
    where number = '$id'";
```

the output of this sql statement is:

`Please find below the link to the FSS: http://blahblack.html`

I need to display the http://blahblack.html as a link at the moment it is displaying as normal text.

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
function hyperlink($text){
    $text = preg_replace("#(http://)+?([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*#", "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $text);
    return $text;
}
```

this might do the job

example usage:
`$str = 'this is a random string which contains a link http://www.yahoo.com'`;

`echo hyperlink($str);`

Comment: `ereg` has been deprecated since 5.3.0 - use PCRE http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Comment: yes i notiched, replaced it with preg_replace. i would need a vote up now :(

Comment: You'll need to add delimiters first

Comment: `return preg_replace_callback('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#',
      create_function('$matches','return "</br></br><a href=\'{$matches[0]}\'>{$matches[0]}</a></br></br>";'),
      $text );`